# Init.d script works when run manually, but not on reboot

Tags: ubuntu, init.d, rhodecode

I'm trying to setup a RhodeCode server on Ubuntu 12.04. I have everything installed into a virtualenv, and everything works properly when I run it from the console (`paster serve production.ini`).

I wrote an init.d script to start it on boot, but it does not seem to work. When I execute `sudo /etc/init.d/rhodecode start` manually, I see "Starting RhodeCode" echoed to the console and everything works. However, if I reboot, or if I use `sudo service rhodecode start`, I do see the message echoed to the console, but the Python processes are not running.

I've installed the script using `update-rc.d rhodecode defaults`.

From researching how to achieve this, the sources I've found have suggested I don't need to run `source /usr/rhode/venv` if I run the python directly from the virtualenv directory. Successfully running this from the console without activating any virtualenv first seems to support this theory. The [virtualenv page seems to confirm this](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv):

> If you directly run a script or the python interpreter from the virtualenv's bin/ directory (e.g. path/to/env/bin/pip or /path/to/env/bin/python script.py) there's no need for activation.

For more details on how I've set the server up, this Gist shows my notes on what I've done so far: [Installing RhodeCode 1.3.6 on Ubuntu Server 12.04](https://gist.github.com/2866413)

### /etc/init.d/rhodecode

```
#!/bin/sh

### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:       rhodecode
# Required-Start: $all
# Required-Stop:  $all
# Default-Start:  2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:   0 1 6
# Short-Description: Starts RhodeCode
### END INIT INFO

USER=rhodeuser

VENV_DIR=/usr/rhode/venv
DATA_DIR=/usr/rhode/data

CELERY_ARGS="$VENV_DIR/bin/paster celeryd $DATA_DIR/production.ini"
RHODECODE_ARGS="$VENV_DIR/bin/paster serve $DATA_DIR/production.ini"

CELERY_PID_FILE=/var/run/celeryd.pid
RHODECODE_PID_FILE=/var/run/rhodecode.pid

start_celery() {
    /sbin/start-stop-daemon \
        --start \
        --background \
        --chuid $USER \
        --pidfile $CELERY_PID_FILE \
        --exec $VENV_DIR/bin/python -- $CELERY_ARGS
}

start_rhodecode() {
    /sbin/start-stop-daemon \
        --start \
        --background \
        --chuid $USER \
        --pidfile $RHODECODE_PID_FILE \
        --exec $VENV_DIR/bin/python -- $RHODECODE_ARGS
}

stop() {
    /sbin/start-stop-daemon \
        --stop \
        --user $USER
}

case "$1" in
    start)
        echo "Starting Celery"
        start_celery
        echo "Starting RhodeCode"
        start_rhodecode
        ;;
    stop)
        echo "Stopping RhodeCode and Celery"
        stop
        ;;
    restart)
        echo "Stopping RhodeCode and Celery"
        stop
        echo "Starting Celery"
        start_celery
        echo "Starting RhodeCode"
        start_rhodecode
        ;;
    *)
        exit 2
        ;;
esac

exit 0
```

Comment: Do you get any error messages ?

Comment: @Iain: None that I can find, though I'm very unfamiliar with Linux servers so I might just not know where to look.

Comment: look in /var/log for logs. If there is nothing relevant there then try redirecting stdout/stderr from the commands in your script to a known file.

Comment: @Iain: I added `1>> /tmp/rhode1.log 2>> /tmp/rhode2.log` to both lines with `--exec`; the files get created but remain empty.

Comment: Whoever is downvoting, let me know what more information I should add. I've added everything I know to be relevant, but I'll add any information you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hate this sort of "answer", but it seems I must have somehow damaged that installation without realizing it. I removed the entire RhodeCode virtualenv and re-created it according to [my notes](https://gist.github.com/2866413), and now the init.d script works properly when I call it via `service rhodecode start`.

I wish I knew what I had done wrong the first time.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the [supplied init.d script](https://rhodecode.org/rhodecode/files/a8d759613d8ff3402ca9108c8390c6787bb70324/init.d/rhodecode-daemon2)?

I think `--exec $DAEMON -- $DAEMON_OPTS` part is missing in your script.

Comment: That line runs paster, which is what my script does.

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you're missing is something to load the virtualenv environment. I've run into the same sort of problems with Ruby's RVM which is similar to virtualenv. Accord to the docs you'll need to use [activate](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv#activate-script) in your script.

Comment: How specifically would I achieve that? I tried [this method](http://blag.felixhummel.de/admin/venv_initd.html) but I couldn't get this to work; the processes didn't seem to want to run as `rhodeuser`.

Comment: Also, if I had to activate the virtualenv first, then why would it work from the console (no virtualenv activated) but not the `service` command?

Comment: I had assumed that your current shell was autoloading virtualenv. I don't see how it could work if you weren't loading virtualenv because otherwise the programs you're trying to run would not be in your path.

Comment: My understanding is that "activating a virtualenv" is just a shortcut for typing "/path/to/venv/bin/python" all the time. The virtualenv website seems to confirm this belief that running the python interpreter in the venv is the same thing (I've edited my question with the quote).

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `source $VENV_DIR/bin/activate` to your script before executing the commands. When you are running it as your own user you have likely already activated the virtual environment.

Comment: I have _not_ activated the virtualenv when I run it from the console. What would be different so that I needed to activate it when I run from `service` but not from the console?